# Просмотр ошибки в браузере при отправке на рассмотрение приложения

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Столкнулся с ситуацией: в личном кабинете в браузере, когда все поля заполнены, нажимаю кнопку "отправить на рассмотрение", и вылетает окошко "на странице 1 или более ошибки", но не показывается, что за ошибка (т.е. если не заполнено какое-то поле или не залит скриншот, то там загорается предупреждение, в моем случае предупреждения не загораются)!

Как мне понять, что эта штука ещё от меня хочет?

P.S. Единственное, что не сделал, - это не залил видео (это обязательно?). И в приложении в разделе localizations оставил только русский язык.

Comment: а описание на русском языке есть?

Comment: да, только на русском - у меня же только русский выбран

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD**

Разобрались, вся проблема была в том, что автор топика не выбрал платежный план приложения.

> Prices -> Free.

Comment: ок, сейчас попробую

Comment: @Bimawa Все равно не дает разместить, а это нормально, что рядом с надписью "1 Prepare for Submission" горит жёлтый кружок?

Comment: @Bimawa конечно)) Мог, конечно, что-то не то написать, например, в Your Bundle ID или SKU, это можно исправить, не создавая новое приложение?